# Probability of joint events which are dependent

Tags: probability-theory, independence

OK, I'm not that good at probability, I'll just admit this beforehand.
I am struggling with the following problem:

> In a specific sporting event 8 teams enter into the quarter finals
> Through lottery the competitors of each of the matches are chosen, one by one.
> Each possible match is equally likely.
>
> The teams are from different nationalities: 3 Canadian teams, 2 Russian teams and a French, English and Swedish team are in the quarter finals
>
> Let A be the event that the two Russian teams play against each other in the quarter finals.
>
> Let B be the event that there are two Canadian teams playing against each other in the quarter finals.
>
> Furthermore, let the random variable X be the number of quarter finals in which two teams from the same country play against each other.
>
> a)Determine P(A) and P(B).
>
> b)Determine P(A|B), P(B|A), P(A [Union] B), P(A [AND] B), P(A - B), P(B - A) and P(A' [Union] B').
>
> c) Are the events A and B disjoint? And are they independent?
>
> d)Determine the probability mass function and the expectation of the random variable X.

The set consists of 8 teams which are {C,C,C,R,R,S,F,E} with S = Sweden, C = Canada, R = Russian, F = France and E = England.
I have concluded from this information that the P(A) = $\frac{2*1}{8*7}$since there are 8 teams of which 2 are Russian.

P(B) = $\frac{3*2}{8*7}$ follows from this same reasoning.

My early reasoning was that the answers to B are quite simple, since it is a matter of using certain equations like :

P(A|B) = $\frac{P(A\bigcap B)}{P(B)}$

However, upon further inspection, the sets are Joint and Dependent right?
This leaves me with a problem in comprehension, as I am no longer aware of how to solve the problem

Comment: Instead of using `sub` and `sup` (html), use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How do you conclude that $P[A] = (2/8)(1/7)$?  One way to compute the true value of $P[A]$ is to take the ratio between the number of (unordered) pairings for which the two Russian teams play each other, and the total number.  Another way is to imagine 4 bins into which the 8 teams are sequentially placed (with 2 in each bin), compute the probability that both Russian teams are in the first bin, then the probability that both Russian teams are in the second bin, and so on.

Comment: For part (b), I believe all the probabilities in question can be computed directly from knowing $P[A], P[B], P[A \cap B]$.  Parts (c) and (d) also seem to follow directly from computing these.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: After a long discussion with @Michael (It's in the comments) I convinced myself that I and the OP were wrong. I'll fix my answer now.

First, this problem can be viewed as placing objects in bins. Each bin represents a match (there are 4 QFs) and each object is a pair of teams. That means that you are not just drawing 2 out of 8 teams for each match, you are doing that *repeatedly* a number of times equal to the number of bins, 4 times.

That means that the probability of getting the two Russians into one match is:

$$
P(A) = \frac{4}{{{8}\choose{2}}} = 4\times \frac{2\times 1}{8\times 7}
$$

The first quotient can be seen as the number of possibilities (1 per bin) divided by the number of unordered pairs that can be drawn from 8 teams. Observe that the probability is 4 times the probability that the OP initially got.

The same can be said from the Canadians:

$$
P(B) = \frac{4}{\frac{{{8}\choose{2}}}{{{3}\choose{2}}}} = 4\times \frac{3\times 2}{8\times 7}
$$

If $B$ is true there's one QF that is already decided (C vs. C), so you can only choose teams out of 6 available. Hence:

$$
P(A \vert B) = 3\times \frac{2\times 1}{6\times 5}
$$

Follow the same reasoning for $P(B \vert A)$ or use Bayes. You can check that $P(A \vert B)P(B) = P(B \vert A)P(A)$.

Comment: This seems to make the same mistake as in the posted attempt to solve for $P[A]$.  I agree you are left with 6 teams, 2 of which are Russian.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how my answer doesn't account for the fact that the Russian teams are undistinguishable. It's just $1/ {{6}\choose{2}}$

Comment: It is not wrong for that reason.  Suppose we have 6 teams, exactly 2 of which are Russian.  Let's give the problem more structure to say that we group the teams into 3 matches, Match 1, Match 2, Match 3 (equivalently, 3 bins).  What is the probability that the Russians play each other in Match 1?

Comment: 1/9. Ok, so what you are saying is that the problem is not equivalent to drawings out of a sample without replacement but to a problem of placing in bins?

Comment: How do you get 1/9?

Comment: (1/3)*(1/3)...?

Comment: I expected you to say “$\frac{1}{6 \choose 2}$” or “$(2/6)(1/5)$.”  Here we have 6 teams, 3 bins, and we place 2 distinct teams in each bin. We are simplifying by focusing on bin 1.

Comment: Ok, still don't get your point

Comment: Why not?  Do you agree the answer to my "bin 1" question is $(2/6)(1/5)$, that this is the _same number_ as you provide in your answer for $P[A|B]$, but that these should be different numbers (so your answer for $P[A|B]$ is not quite right)? (since the original quesiton does not care which bin the Russians are placed, as long as they are placed in the same bin).

Comment: Ok, so you need to multiply that by 3 to get all the possible bins?

Comment: yes.  .......[I need to wrote more characters for this comment to go thru]

Comment: There's something that bothers me: If in the 1st bin you don't place the Russians, then the number of available teams to place in the 2nd bin has diminished, so it's not multiplying by 3, isn't it?

Comment: I think of it like this (with "O" representing "other," i.e., "nonRussian"):  $$[RR][OO][OO] \mbox{ or } [OO][RR][OO] \mbox{ or } [OO][OO][RR]$$ If you think about choosing teams sequentially to fill each bin slot, you can just look at the first two slots and compute $P[[RR][OO][OO]]=(2/6)(1/5)$.  Can you compute $P[[OO][RR][OO]]$? (it will be a multiplication of 4 probabilities if you use the sequential method...but you should then notice something about that multiplication).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to think for a while to convince myself that you were right, and I finally did. I'm editing my answer now.

Comment: Though I am partially agreeing with your reasoning, doesn't this imply that you are replacing the teams? Once a team is in a match it automatically cannot be in another right? From this, the 4* multiplication is not correct right?

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing. Think about 6 teams to be placed in three matches. The possibilities are ${{6}\choose{2}}$ while the only favorable cases are 3: they both go to match 1, 2 or 3. Hence the probability is $3/{{6}\choose{2}}$

Comment: Yeah, but, when considering the fact thet when any match is filled with two teams, the amount of teams decreases, and the chance that Russian teams get matched either increases, or decreases to 0 completely right?

Comment: I think that this confusion comes from the fact that we need to realize that the three matches are set up simultaneously. If you want think of the number ${{6}\choose{2}}$ as the number of ways you can pick 2 slots out of 6, there are only three favorable configurations, the slots are consecutive AND they are the first and the second (match 1), the third and the fourth (match 2) or the fifth and the sixth (match 3). Any other pair of slots would place the Russian teams in different QFs